# Correct way to merge a git branch into mine, with a submodule

Tags: git, merge, git-submodules

This has to be a dupe, but I can't find a search phrase that finds me the answer.

I have a git repo (`foo`) with one submodule, pointing at commit `abc123` of another repo (`bar`).

I have a long-ish lived branch of `foo` still pointing at commit `abc123`.

Changes happen on `foo`'s `main` branch, including an update to the submodule, moving it to commit `zyx987`.

Now I want to merge `main` into my branch.

Normally I would just do `git merge main`. With the submodule, that shows me:

```
# On branch feature
# All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
#  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#
#       ...
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:  bar (new commits)
#
```

When I navigate into the `bar` directory, and do a `git status`, I see it's still at the previous commit (`abc123`). I've tried `git add bar`, but that kept it at `abc123`.

The only way I found to get the new commit, was to navigate into the submodule's directory and manually issue `git checkout zyx987`.

There's obviously scope for errors to creep in here, I could easily miss the fact that the submodule changed, or select the wrong commit when I manually update it, not to mention that it's additional work that I, as the developer working on the (unrelated) feature branch, shouldn't need to care about what's going on in that submodule.

Is there a way to say "merge, and update the submodule" or (better) after a normal `git merge`, when you discover that the submodule has changed, to accept the commit that was selected in the source branch?

Comment: While that feels suboptimal to you, it looks and feels pretty optimal to me. Note that you can use `git -C submodule checkout <hash>` as a slight short-cut (though since I use shells capable of starting sub-shells, I just tend to do `(cd submodule; git checkout <hash>)` myself). It's always wise to build and test the entire thing with the alternate submodule hash ID checked out since submodule linkage like this tends to be brittle.

Comment: @torek, thanks for this. I realised that just saying "sub-optimal" was a pretty sub-optimal way to describe my thoughts. I've made a small edit - I guess the main thing it feels like I'm missing is the answer to the mid-merge question "oh, I see the submodule's been updated, how do I get that change?". It feels like there should be something I can do to easily "accept theirs".

Comment: You might look at recent Git mailing list messages: there's a new merge strategy, `-s ort`, in the works. It's up to the merge strategy to figure out what to do with submodule hash IDs in the index. The regular (recursive and resolve) merge strategy doesn't do anything good...

Comment: Regarding the close vote, I didn't intend this to be opinion-based, and have modified the language that could have been misleading. Hopefully the final paragraph, asking a specific question, is clearly enough not opinion-based.